# Truncate selected tables from mySQL database using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listbox, truncate

I had populated a listbox with all my tables in the database with the query below:

```
Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("SHOW TABLES", con)
Dim reader As OdbcDataReader
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
While reader.Read
allTables.Items.Add(reader(0).ToString)
End While
```

Using buttons i moved some table that can't be `Truncated` to another listBox named `safeTables`.

Now am having two `listBoxws`

- `allTables` : List of all tables
- `safeTables` : List of tables that can't be `Truncated`
  How can i perform the operation? Can anyone suggest me the best method to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using an ODBC instead of the proper ADO.NET provider for MySql? (MySql.Data.SqlClient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `btnTruncate` be a button its click event will truncate some tables expect `safeTables` in the second list: now see the following code:

```
Private Sub btnTruncate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTruncate.Click
    Dim tableList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Dim notDelete As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    tableList.AddRange(allTables.Items)
    notDelete.AddRange(tableToRemove)
    truncateTables(tableList, notDelete)
End Sub

 Public Sub truncateTables(ByVal tableToTruncate As List(Of String), ByVal safeTables As List(Of String))
        con.Open()
        For Each table As String In tableToTruncate
            If Not safeTables.Contains(table) Then
                Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("truncate table " & table, con)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        Next
 End Sub
```